# Labelling of molecular motor isomeric forms as trans and cis

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I am reading [Koumura *et al.* (2002)](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja012499i), a paper about molecular motors. It contains this figure:

[image]

Being an absolute layman when it comes to naming my molecules I'm a little confused as to why the left molecules are trans, while the right molecules are cis. Which groups are being compared to each other? The benzene ring and the MeO group?

I always learned that one should only use trans/cis if there is absolutely no ambiguity possible, and E/Z otherwise. Isn't this situation ambiguous? One could also compare MeO and Me!

Comment: Well, I guess you're right in saying it's unclear.

Comment: Here things are more clear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_molecular_motor#Light-driven_rotary_molecular_motors

Comment: In my opinion it just show that sometimes is hard to be pedantic. But it is also pity that IUPAC rules/recommendations are neglected in works leading to nobel prizes in chemistry.